# UNITY- Camera Zoom in and out with character movement

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I am making a game where it's a beat em up side scroller. I want the camera to zoom in on the player when the player in going in the Z direction, meaning in depth. I can make the camera follow him in the X axis but I can't seem to figure out how to make the camera follow him the Z- axis as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :))))

Answer (score 0):

Camera follow simple way, you can config m_OffetPosition to update Camera position.

```
public class CameraController : Monobehaviour {

    public Transform target;    
    public Vector3 m_OffsetPosition;
    public float m_speed = 0.1f;

    public void Awake ()
    {

    }

    public void LateUpdate() {
        if (target != null) {
            m_Transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (m_Transform.position, target.transform.position + m_OffsetPosition, m_speed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is base.Awake in this case? When I tried this code, Visual Studios couldn't figure out what it meant.